# Pattern Matching in C#

Tags: c#

This is my serial port received data on a textbox.

```
Current consumed by device : 0.45
Power consumption: = [ 103.2277 ]
ENERGY CONSUMED: = [ 24.250 ]
Length = 6

Current consumed by device : 0.45
Power consumption: = [ 103.5094 ]
ENERGY CONSUMED: = [ 24.250 ]
Length = 4
```

I want to extract only the values of "Power Consumption" and "Energy Consumed" and display it in a textbox separately, every time is comes through serial port.

How do i parse this effectively and efficiently?

here's my code

```
enter code here

        Regex regex = new Regex(@"(Power consumption: (.*?) ])");
        Match match = regex.Match(temp);
        if (match.Success)
        {
            string abc = match.Value;
            string res = new string(abc.SkipWhile(c => c != '[')
                       .Skip(1)
                       .TakeWhile(c => c != ']')
                       .ToArray()).Trim();
            float f_num = float.Parse(res);
            //   trackBar1.Value = (int)f_num;

            textBox2.Text = f_num.ToString();
```

please suggest me an faster code.

Comment: regular expression would be your best bet.

Comment: i have tried it.. heres my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to adjust the carriage returns/line feeds but this should work:

```
string text =
    "Current consumed by device : 0.45\r\nPower consumption: = [ 103.2277 ]\r\nENERGY CONSUMED: = [ 24.250 ]\r\nLength = 6\r\n\r\n"
    + "Current consumed by device : 0.45\r\nPower consumption: = [ 103.5094 ]\r\nENERGY CONSUMED: = [ 24.250 ]\r\nLength = 4\r\n";

Regex regex = new Regex(@"Power consumption:\s=\s\[\s(?<PowerConsumption>\d*.\d*)\s\]\r\nENERGY CONSUMED:\s=\s\[\s(?<EnergyConsumed>\d*.\d*)\s\]");

MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(text);

foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Power Consumption: " + match.Groups["PowerConsumption"].Value);
    Console.WriteLine("Energy Consumed: " + match.Groups["EnergyConsumed"].Value);
}
```

Gives:

> Power Consumption: 103.2277
>
> Energy Consumed: 24.250
>
> Power Consumption: 103.5094
>
> Energy Consumed: 24.250